# force munin regeneration of all graphs

Tags: centos, rrdtool, munin

I have configured `munin` to fetch logs from another server yesterday and also custom configured based on the config example a `Totals` for both server loads.

I used `rrdtool` to convert the `rrd` files to `xml` and copy them over and convert them back to `rrd` for the new machine in order to bring over it's history.

Now it worked nicely but the totals seemed to have stopped generating after a while. I checked the logs and it was saying that the load2-day.png ... and so on files are not found.

I checked and they are there, `chown` and `chmod` match `munin`.

Any ideas on why it might not see the files and once I get it to see them how can I force a complete graphs regeneration so I don't have to wait 5 minutes to find out if it works?

**Complete logs here:**

The `perl` errors seems to not affect anything, though I would appreciate a hint on removing it.

```
2013/09/10 13:45:10 Starting munin-graph
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 758.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 775.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 784.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 786.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 787.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 758.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 775.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 784.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 786.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 787.
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load2-month.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load2-week.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load2-day.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load2-year.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [INFO] Graphed service example.com;Totals:load2 (0.05 sec)
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load3-month.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load3-week.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load3-day.png : opening '': No such file or directory
2013/09/10 13:45:10 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/html/munin/example.com/Totals/load3-year.png : opening '': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RRD ERROR lines are indicating the graphs (pngs) can't be created because something in RRD is unable to find (or open) some file.  This snippet is saying it's trying to open a blank path, and failing.

```
opening '': No such file or directory
```

The perl error mentions an "uninitialized value $filename", which given the RRD error is probably part of the problem.  Since the graphs are generated out of the RRD files, the likely issue is that the system can't find your RRDs.  Consequently, you'll want to check that everything about specifying the location of your RRDs is in order.

- Confirm the dbdir directive in munin.conf is correct
- Confirm your RRDs are present in the $dbdir/domain/ path
- Confirm filesystem permissions allow the munin process to read and write said path
- Confirm the host tree (in munin.conf) is correct for the client you're having trouble with

Regarding triggering graph creation: the munin server is driven by cron.  You should be able to find a cron job which you can manually run as the munin user in order to trigger the process.  The RPM I've used in the past has this job at /etc/cron.d/munin